# Can htpasswd handle multiple directories

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu

I need to password protect two directories with one user account in Apache.  Will I need two Directory sections, or is there a way to combine them together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both using the `DirectoryMatch` [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directorymatch) (regex basic skills required)

Answer (score 2):

You could list two `<Directory>` sections, but refer to the same `htpasswd` file; is that what you meant…? I presume that these aren't a directory, and one that it also contains…

Comment: I was hoping to avoid two directory sections, it appears @thinice has pointed me in the right direction.